# Can a private LAN be restricted by WAN operators in terms of number of devices connected to the router?

Tags: networking, router, lan

I want to know the myths and facts about my recent conversation with a network admin in a hotel.

In every event I manage, I always ask for a single uplink to my own router. I plug the uplink to my router WAN port and then manage my private LAN from that router utilizing the internet connection of the uplink.

This works most of the time until recently the venue told us we cannot use more than 3 computers on a 30Mbps uplink. They want me to order 10Mbps uplink for each computer if I will use more than 3 computers. My request is to give me single gigabit uplink with 30Mbps internet speed and I will manage it from my router.

Is this really possible? In my understanding, from my router, all devices is invisible to their network. Only my router is visible to them. With that, I can put as many devices I want as long as my router supports it.

The only thing they can restrict me from is the bandwidth of the uplink but not the number of devices I connect on my router.

Am I wrong?

If I am I have to look for another venue but if I am right I will just let the man believe what he thinks he can control.

Thanks

Comment: They have no visibility into your network, but depending on the traffic they can see the number of open sessions, DNS requests and other things, they can't directly see how many nodes are on your network regardless if you have 1 or 2000. Make sure your router is caching DNS requests (router is the DNS server for the internal devices) or you use a public DNS server like Google or OpenDNS and you should be good. If 30Mbps is all you need, then there is no need to pay for more regardless of the number nodes on your network. They are trying to get more money out of you.

Comment: if you are really that worried about it, use a router that supports an infrastructure VPN tunnel, and just pass all your traffic through it. That would defeat just about any attempt to identify the talkers on the interior of the LAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your wireless or wired firewall hands out its own IP addresses to clients by providing its own DHCP and DNS, making them invisible to your WAN side of your firewall.**  All the DNS requests are usually processed through your router.  But just to be sure you don't expose your requests, you can change the DNS provider to Google: "Google Public DNS is a free, global Domain Name System (DNS) ... Configure your network settings to use the IP addresses 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 as your DNS servers."  The whole purpose of your router it to provide NAT and make all your clients invisible to the outside WAN, which in this case, is another LAN.

**Ignore them...  They are just trying to extract $$ from you, or they are just ignorant.**  In the early days of the internet, I had an ISP that offered DSL to my company, and insisted that I pay per client connected, charging me for each clients' email, etc.  I refused and as per my contract with them, I insisted that I was going to only connect my firewall.  I had a running battle anytime I talked to their support staff, who couldn't quite understand that I was intentionally only paying for one client.  They only saw one client connected to the DSL modem, my SonicWall firewall, which fed the rest of our network and supported hundreds of clients.

**As a workaround, you could also provide service via tethering from your mobile provider to your firewall.**  Just make sure in this case that all your clients have turned off updates for Windows, and all your other applications as well, and then also turn off all other sync programs that aren't running.  (We still check for Windows Defender updates every hour though, since these are small).  If possible, disable Flash and any browser animation as well.  If you do all this, you'd be amazed at how little internet you will be using, even when connecting many clients.